# Can't install json-.0.4.4 - memory allocation failed

Tags: json, haskell, ghc, cabal

I tried to install the json-0.4.4 package on Mac OS 10.5.8, and got this error:

```
$ sudo cabal install "json-0.4.4"
Building json-0.4.4...
[1 of 7] Compiling Text.JSON.Types  ( Text/JSON/Types.hs,
dist/build/Text/JSON/Types.o )
[2 of 7] Compiling Text.JSON.Pretty ( Text/JSON/Pretty.hs,
dist/build/Text/JSON/Pretty.o )
[3 of 7] Compiling Text.JSON.ReadP  ( Text/JSON/ReadP.hs,
dist/build/Text/JSON/ReadP.o )

Text/JSON/ReadP.hs:104:21:
    Warning: A do-notation statement discarded a result of type b.
             Suppress this warning by saying "_ <- n",
             or by using the flag -fno-warn-unused-do-bind
[4 of 7] Compiling Text.JSON.Parsec ( Text/JSON/Parsec.hs,
dist/build/Text/JSON/Parsec.o )
ghc: memory allocation failed (requested 2097152 bytes)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
json-0.4.4 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

This is on a machine with 16GB of RAM.

I don't think
http://www.haskell.org/cabal/FAQ.html#cabal-goes-into-an-infinite-loop--runs-out-of-memory
applies because I'm using higher versions than mentioned there:

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.12.3
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.8.2
using version 1.8.0.6 of the Cabal library
```

Why did I not install the latest version of the JSON package?

```
$ sudo cabal install json
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: dependencies conflict: base-3.0.3.2 requires syb ==0.1.0.2 however
syb-0.1.0.2 was excluded because json-0.7 requires syb >=0.3.3
```

Updating base IIUC would mean updating my whole Haskell Platform installation, and I already have the newest version for which a Mac OS 10.5 binary is available. I could build from source, or use port or brew, but I'd rather just have the json package build.

I know Mac OS 10.5.8 is old, but unfortunately upgrading this
particular machine is not an option.

Comment: I just want to point out (also w.r.t. the answer already provided) that this does not seem to be a Cabal problem. It's ghc that's running out of memory during compilation of a specific source file.

Answer (score 6):

It may not be an infinite loop--I have had installations (specifically HSX on a VPS with limited RAM) fail due to simple shortage of memory. I would try using the compacting collector (which fixed my problem):

```
sudo cabal install json-0.4.4 --ghc-options="+RTS -c -RTS"
```

If even that fails, you can try setting the heap size with -M (again inside the RTS options), but I can provide less help with that.

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work. Same error. I added -M4095M in between +RTS and -RTS to set the heap size to the largest available, that didn't change anything. Did not seem to matter whether I had the compacting collector on or not.

Comment: Hm. In that case, my best remaining advice would be to upgrade GHC. The GHC OS X installers seem to rely on 10.7, but you should be able to install from source using your existing installation (and I would recommend only going to 7.4; 7.6 is quite new and a lot of libraries lack a compatible tagged release).